# Nodebb--[nodebb-plugin-custom-pages] Custom Static pages

Tags: nodebb

I have recently set up a community site on Nodebb and I'm having issues with the custom static pages plug-in. Initially, when Nodebb reloaded my content would delete. After fixing this issue by hosting the nodebb site elsewhere, we realized that the nodebb plugins still live locally. The custom static pages are not working. The site only has the capability of supporting one custom static page and the rest show up with this error: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQxaG.png

(This is not the only type of error, it's just the most recent one that keeps coming up.) I need to integrate static pages on my site. Any ideas as to how I can fix this issue? Or any suggestions for another option that could incorporate static pages on nodebb? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue with custom static pages plugin. I initially found out that even after the restart it wasn't creating the tpl files in the build/public/templates folder. That was causing the page not found error like you.

- A hacky fix that worked for me was to create a tpl file with the name of the route. This solved the error and i was able to see the custom page.
- Proper fix that worked for me were these steps in order

  - Uninstall the plugin
  - Stop the nodebb app
  - Install the plugin via command-line i.e `npm install nodebb-plugin-custom-pages`
  - Remove the manually created tpl files in `build/public/templates`
  - Start Nodebb app.

Hope it helps.

NodeBB version 1.4

Comment: Another potential issue could be folder and file creation permissions. e.g if your nodebb user is nodebb make sure it build and other internal folders are given write permissions to nodebb

sudo chown -R nodebb:nodebb /var/www/